# checksum code in client server communication

Tags: c, client-server, checksum

I have written a code to send a TCP packet and receive acknowledgement packet.

I want to implement checksum in the code to check data consistency but failed to write the code(in C language) for checking the data consistency.

Please give me the code.

Comment: Look through all the menus of your IDE and find the menu item saying `Give me the code` and then select it.

Answer (score 1):

The usual way to do this is to use one of the [zlib checksum functions](http://www.zlib.net/manual.html#Checksum), such as `crc32`.

At the top of your source code add

```
#include <zlib.h>
```

The initialize the CRC with something like

```
my_crc = crc32(0L, Z_NULL, 0);
```

Then add data as many times as required, usually in some loop context

```
my_crc = crc32(my_crc, (unsigned char *)some_buffer_pointer, length_of_buffer);
```

Remember to link with the zlib library

```
-lz
```

If you don't want to use a library function because, for example, you are on an MPU, then you can use http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-1456.1.26/bsd/libkern/crc32.c?txt.

If you don't have zlib on your platform you can download it from http://www.zlib.net/.

Hopefully someone else will suggest what to use if you are on Windows.